# DateType() definition giving Null in PySpark?

Tags: pyspark

I have dates which are big endian like:
YYYYMMDD in a CSV.

When I use simple string types, the data loads in correctly but when I used the DateType() object to define the column, I get nulls for everything. Am I able to define the date format somewhere or should Spark infer this automatically?

```
schema_comments= StructType([
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("date", DateType(), True),
])
```

Comment: I can use IntegerType for that field too.

Comment: Can you add how you read data?

Comment: how are you reading the csv is it by pandas or from pyspark

Answer (score 2):

The schema looks good to me.
You can define how spark reads the CSV using `dateFormat`.

**For example:**

```
rc = spark.read.csv('yourCSV.csv', header=False,
                    dateFormat="yyyyddMM", schema=schema)
```

Answer (score 1):

DateType expect standard timestamp format in spark so if you are providing it in schema it should be of the format 1997-02-28 10:30:00 if that's not the case read it using pandas or pyspark in string format and then you can convert it into a DateType() object using python and pyspark. Below is the sample code to convert the YYYYMMDD format into DateType in pyspark :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp

df2 = df.select('date_str', from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('date_str', 'yyyyMMdd')).alias('date'))
```